# Spring Security SwitchUserFilter and userDetailsService

Tags: spring-security

Environment:

- spring-xxx-3.1.0-Release for all spring related dependencies
- Java 1.6
- Tomcat 6

I've implemented Spring security and am using an annotation-driven approach.  Everything appears to be configured correctly, but when the SwitchUserFilter attemptSwitchUser method executes, the userDetailsService is always null.  I CAN step through this class with the debugger when I start tomcat, and userDetailsService is NOT null.  However when I invoke the attemptSwitchUser method manually, userDetailsService is always null.  Here's my xml config:

applicationContext-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd

http://www.springframework.org/schema/security

http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <form-login login-page="/login.do" default-target-url="/dashboard.do" authentication-failure-url="/login.do?login_error=true" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.do" access="permitAll" />

    <!-- ADMIN -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/viewRoles.do" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/createNewRole.do" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/viewOrgs.do" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_switch_user"     access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <session-management>
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="2" />
    </session-management>       
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="md5" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
</b:beans>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd            
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd">

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.vitaminj.repository" />

<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.vitaminj"></context:component-scan>

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties"></context:property-placeholder>

<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
    id="messageSource" p:basename="Messages">
</bean>

<!--  File Uploads  -->
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- Max size in bytes. -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="16777215"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
    id="dataSource" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" p:url="${jdbc.url}" p:username="${jdbc.username}">
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
    id="sessionFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.vitaminj"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:persistenceXmlLocation="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"
    p:persistenceUnitName="vitaminJPersistence" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
    p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="hibernateVendor" />

<bean id="hibernateVendor"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
    p:showSql="false" />

<!-- <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="vitaminJPersistence" /> <property 
    name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" 
    /> <property name="loadTimeWeaver"> <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" 
    /> </property> </bean> -->

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="switchUserProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter">

    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    <property name="switchUserUrl" value="/j_spring_security_switch_user" />
    <property name="exitUserUrl" value="/j_spring_security_exit_user" />
    <property name="targetUrl" value="/dashboard.do" />
</bean>

<!-- <bean id="ajaxTimeoutRedirectFilter" class="com.vitaminj.web.filter.AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter">

</bean> -->

<!-- Begin Quartz config -->    
<bean class="com.vitaminj.quartz.QuartzJobSchedulingListener"></bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobFactory">
        <bean class="com.vitaminj.quartz.SpringQuartzJobFactory"></bean>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

jsp:

```
<form action='j_spring_security_switch_user' method='POST'>
 Switch to user: <input type='text' name='j_username' value='builderbob'/> <br/>
  <input type='submit' value='Switch'/>
</form>
```

I left out web.xml mistakenly.  The SwitchUserFilter is in fact getting called.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>companyname</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:applicationContext.xml
        classpath:applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>


<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>switchUserProcessingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>switchUserProcessingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/j_spring_security_switch_user</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>openSessionInViewFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Without fail, in line 209 of the SwitchUserFilter, the userDetailsService is ALWAYS null upon submitting the form post to j_spring_security_switch_user.  It would seem to me that it's not getting injected when the filter runs, however it is referenced in the SwitchUserProcessingFilter correctly from all of the examples I've seen.  I've searched and been unable to find any clues. Thanks in advance for any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: Is this really the configuration you are using? There's no SwitchUserFilter in the filter chain at all, so it's hard to believe you would get anything other than an HTTP error from submitting the form. Are you saying you get a NPE at line 209? If so, then your web configuration must be different.

Comment: I left out web.xml.  Added to the original post.  Thanks for the view.  Stack trace
java.lang.NullPointerException
 org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter.attemptSwitchUser(SwitchUserFilter.java:209)
 org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter.doFilter(SwitchUserFilter.java:155)
 org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Security filters are not meant to be used directly in the web.xml. Quickly read through [section 8.1 and 8.2](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/security-filter-chain.html#delegating-filter-proxy) of the reference docs that describe how the Security Filter Chain is set up. You will need something like the following in your spring security config:

```
<!-- declare the filter bean -->
<beans:bean id="switchUserFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    <beans:property name="switchUserUrl" value="/j_spring_security_switch_user" />
    <beans:property name="exitUserUrl" value="/j_spring_security_exit_user" />
    <beans:property name="targetUrl" value="/" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- include it in the security filter chain -->
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    ...
    <custom-filter ref="switchUserFilter" position="SWITCH_USER_FILTER"/>
</http>
```

Comment: Beautiful.  That makes perfect sense and works perfectly as well.  One last question...  Now that I have effectively switched users, I would like to render a link in my JSP header page that will allow me to go back to the ROLE_ADMIN user after he or she is finished with whatever they were doing in the account they switched to.  How can I use the security context to conditionally render this "switch back" link?  I know the url is /j_spring_security_exit_user, but I don't know how I would conditionally render it based on the the contents of the security context.